# How to group different elements in one single div

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

verse outputclass elements in to a single group of element of div elment to the verse elements as shown in the below format

My XML code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC>
<topic id="topic_31" xml:lang="en-US" outputclass="Back-Matter">
  <title>Back-Matter</title>
  <body>
    <p outputclass="E-Head">E-Head</p>
    <p outputclass="F-Head">F-Head</p>
    <p outputclass="Body-Text">Body-Text (Tx)</p>
    <p outputclass="Body-Text-ContinuedTxc">Body-Text-Continued</p>
    <p outputclass="Verse1">Verse1 (Vrs1)</p>
    <p outputclass="Verse1-indent1">Verse1-indent1 (Vrs1-i1)</p>
    <p outputclass="Verse1-indent2">Verse1-indent2 (Vrs1-i2)</p>
    <p outputclass="Verse1-indent3">Verse1-indent3 (Vrs1-i3)</p>
    <p outputclass="Verse2Vrs2">Verse2 (Vrs2)</p>
    <p outputclass="Verse2-indent1Vrs2-i1">Verse2-indent1 (Vrs2-i1)</p>
    <p outputclass="Verse2-indent2Vrs2-i2">Verse2-indent2 (Vrs2-i2)</p>
    <p outputclass="Verse2-indent3Vrs2-i3">Verse2-indent3 (Vrs2-i3)</p>
    <p outputclass="QuotationQuo">Quotation (Quo)</p>
    <p outputclass="Extract1Ext1">Extract1 (Ext1)</p>
    <p outputclass="Extract2Ext2">Extract2 (Ext2)</p>
    <p outputclass="E-Head">E-Head</p>
    <p outputclass="F-Head">F-Head</p>
    <p outputclass="Body-Text">Body-Text (Tx)</p>
    <p outputclass="Body-Text-ContinuedTxc">Body-Text-Continued</p>
    <p outputclass="Verse1">Verse1 (Vrs1)</p>
    <p outputclass="Verse1-indent1">Verse1-indent1 (Vrs1-i1)</p>
    <p outputclass="Verse1-indent2">Verse1-indent2 (Vrs1-i2)</p>
    <p outputclass="Verse1-indent3">Verse1-indent3 (Vrs1-i3)</p>
    <p outputclass="Verse2Vrs2">Verse2 (Vrs2)</p>
    <p outputclass="Verse2-indent1Vrs2-i1">Verse2-indent1 (Vrs2-i1)</p>
    <p outputclass="Verse2-indent2Vrs2-i2">Verse2-indent2 (Vrs2-i2)</p>
    <p outputclass="Verse2-indent3Vrs2-i3">Verse2-indent3 (Vrs2-i3)</p>
    <p outputclass="QuotationQuo">Quotation (Quo)</p>
    <p outputclass="Extract1Ext1">Extract1 (Ext1)</p>
    <p outputclass="Extract2Ext2">Extract2 (Ext2)</p>
    </body>
</topic>
```

Need output as any where "verse" used in output class we want as div root element end after combination of verse elements completed as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xml:lang="en-us" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Styles</title>
</head>
<body class="Back-Matter" id="topic_31">
<section>
<h6 class="E-Head">E-Head</h6>
<section>
<h6 class="F-Head">F-Head</h6>
<section>
<p class="Body-Text">Body-Text</p>
<p class="Body-Text-Continued">Body-Text-Continued</p>
<div class="verse_group">
<p class="Verse1">Verse1</p>
<p class="Verse1-indent1">Verse1-indent1</p>
<p class="Verse1-indent2">Verse1-indent2</p>
<p class="Verse1-indent3">Verse1-indent3</p>
<p class="Verse2">Verse2</p>
<p class="Verse2-indent1">Verse2-indent1</p>
<p class="Verse2-indent2">Verse2-indent2</p>
<p class="Verse2-indent3">Verse2-indent3</p>
</div>
<p class="Quotation">Quotation</p>
<p class="Extract1">Extract1</p>
<p class="Extract2">Extract2</p>
</section>
</section>
<h6 class="E-Head">E-Head</h6>
<section>
<h6 class="F-Head">F-Head</h6>
<section>
<p class="Body-Text">Body-Text</p>
<p class="Body-Text-Continued">Body-Text-Continued</p>
<div class="verse_group">
<p class="Verse1">Verse1</p>
<p class="Verse1-indent1">Verse1-indent1</p>
<p class="Verse1-indent2">Verse1-indent2</p>
<p class="Verse1-indent3">Verse1-indent3</p>
<p class="Verse2">Verse2</p>
<p class="Verse2-indent1">Verse2-indent1</p>
<p class="Verse2-indent2">Verse2-indent2</p>
<p class="Verse2-indent3">Verse2-indent3</p>
</div>
<p class="Quotation">Quotation</p>
<p class="Extract1">Extract1</p>
<p class="Extract2">Extract2</p>
</section>
</section>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

MY Xslt template Code for topic.p template:

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' topic/p ')]" name="topic.p">
<xsl:variable name="topicatt"><xsl:value-of select="@outputclass" /></xsl:variable>
<xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="descendant::*[contains(@class, ' topic/pre ')] or
        descendant::*[contains(@class, ' topic/ul ')] or
        descendant::*[contains(@class, ' topic/sl ')] or
        descendant::*[contains(@class, ' topic/ol ')] or
        descendant::*[contains(@class, ' topic/lq ')] or
        descendant::*[contains(@class, ' topic/dl ')] or
        descendant::*[contains(@class, ' topic/note ')] or
        descendant::*[contains(@class, ' topic/lines ')] or
        descendant::*[contains(@class, ' topic/fig ')] or
        descendant::*[contains(@class, ' topic/table ')] or
        descendant::*[contains(@class, ' topic/simpletable ')]">
        <div class="p">
          <xsl:call-template name="commonattributes"/>
          <xsl:call-template name="setid"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$topicatt = 'E-Head'">
        <h6 class="E-Head"><xsl:apply-templates/></h6>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$topicatt = 'F-Head'">
        <h6 class="F-Head"><xsl:apply-templates/></h6>
      </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="output_p_element"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="output_p_element">
    <p>
      <xsl:call-template name="commonattributes"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="setid"/>
      <xsl:if test="contains(@outputclass, 'EntryIdx')">
        <xsl:call-template name="set_index_entry_class"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
```

Adding the verse output class elements in a div element.

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you done any exercise for this?

Comment: Yes @Amredra Kumar, I have edited my question template which used by me

Comment: As you have tagged the question as `[tag:xslt-2.0]` it seems a textbook example for using `<xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-adjacent="starts-with(@outputclass, 'Verse')">`

Comment: See also the example "Grouping Alternating Sequences of Elements" in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples.

Comment: Yes, @MartinHonnen, I am using XSlt 2.0 and as per your suggestion i have added the code <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-adjacent="starts-with(@outputclass, 'Verse')">
      <div class="verse_group">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each-group> but there is no difference in output

Answer (score 0):

If your only task is wrapping adjacent `p` elements with the `Verse` string in the `outputclass` element then this is a text book example (see example "Grouping Alternating Sequences of Elements" in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples for instance) of using XSLT 2/3's `for-each-group group-adjacent`:

```
  <xsl:template match="body">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="starts-with(@outputclass, 'Verse')">
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                      <div class="verse_group">
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                      </div>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template>
```

Full example at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMK.

You seem to want to nest the contents as well, I suspect doing that with `for-each-group group-starting-with="*[@outputclass = 'E-Head']"` nested with another one for the other `F-Head` and then nested inside with above `group-adjacent` (where all the nested grouping works on `current-group()` instead of the full selection of `*` or `p` of course) could solve that but it might be better splitting that up into different questions.

Comment: Can you please guide me is it possible to get the exact output for coding inside this template using when condition <xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' topic/p ')]" name="topic.p"> because i am using book formats

Comment: No, I can't, if the posted input sample has no element matching `match="*[contains(@class, ' topic/p ')]"` at all I can't guess what the code is good for in the context of the presented input example and the presented wanted output. You will need to ask a new question with the relevant and matching details if you need help with that.